# Transloco does NOT work in my Angular 12 Prod Build, while it works in my DEV build. What could I be missing?

Tags: angular, production-environment, angular12, transloco

When I run my Angular 12 application locally using `npm start` the Transloco translations work fine.

However, after an `ng build --configuration production` when I run my application using `http-server dist/my-project` the translations don't work - I see the raw values.

Here's my ***transloco-root.module.ts***:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import {
  Translation,
  TRANSLOCO_CONFIG,
  TRANSLOCO_LOADER,
  translocoConfig,
  TranslocoLoader,
  TranslocoModule
} from "@ngneat/transloco";
import { Injectable, NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class TranslocoHttpLoader implements TranslocoLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getTranslation(lang: string) {
    return this.http.get<Translation>(`/assets/i18n/${lang}.json`);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [TranslocoModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: TRANSLOCO_CONFIG,
      useValue: translocoConfig({
        availableLangs: ["hin", "eng", "tel"],
        defaultLang: "eng",
        reRenderOnLangChange: true,
        prodMode: environment.production,
        fallbackLang: "hin",
        failedRetries: 1,
        missingHandler: {
          allowEmpty: true,
          useFallbackTranslation: true
        },
        flatten: {
          aot: environment.production
        }
      })
    },
    { provide: TRANSLOCO_LOADER, useClass: TranslocoHttpLoader }
  ]
})
export class TranslocoRootModule {
}
```

Here's my ***transloco.config.js***:

```
module.exports = {
  rootTranslationsPath: 'src/assets/i18n/',
  langs: ['hin', 'eng', 'tel'],
  keysManager: {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Odd... But this worked for me:

Removing the entry from providers makes the translation work in Prod Mode.

```
        flatten: {
          aot: environment.production,
        },
```

Any ideas why?